# How to return data after asynchronous function completes

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

Let's say I have a following folder structure:

```
People
|
|── John
|   |── img.png
|   |── info.json 
|── Craig
|   |── img.png
|   |── info.json
|── Daniel
|   |── img.png
|   |── info.json
```

I would like to get the `info.json` of every folder listed in `People` folder. To do that, I've written a function:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import "dart:io";


Directory folderPath = Directory("/storage/people/");
Future<List> getData() async {

      List data = [];

      folderPath.list().listen((e) async { //for every entity in directory
        var path = e.path;
        File infoFile = File("$path/info.json");
        String infoString = await infoFile.readAsString();
        Map info = jsonDecode(infoString);
        data.add(item);
       });
       return data;
  }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Function doesn't wait for the loop to end, and returns `data` as empty.

Is there any way for the function to return data after the loop is completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this;

```
Directory folderPath = Directory("/storage/people/");
Future<List> getData() async {
  List data = [];
  List<FileSystemEntity> entities = folderPath.listSync();

  for (FileSystemEntity e in entities) {
    var path = e.path;
    File infoFile = File("$path/info.json");
    String infoString = await infoFile.readAsString();
    Map info = json.decode(infoString);
    data.add(info);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a native for-loop on the folderPath.list() instead.
In Dart using a for loop will automatically tell the function to wait for it to end before returning anything.